# using regex to get a substring from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in the form of:

*`integer`, `integer`, a comma separated list of strings, integer*

for example:

```
"0, 0, ['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU'], 1"
```

I want to return this substring `['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU']`

I thought of using `split(", ")` and then joining things together but it will just be so complicated. How to do that with regex?

Comment: What syntax is that input? Is it perhaps compatible with Python source code? Can you use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

Comment: Can the 'internal' strings contain `[` or `]` characters?

Comment: @TomDalton No. This is a good question. I should have mentioned that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a regular expression to capture a group that consist of a `[`, any characters and then a `]`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "0, 0, ['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU'], 1"
>>> re.search(r'(\[.*\])', s).group(1)
"['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU']"
```

If the input really is this well structured, you could use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)[2]
['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU']
```

To safely evaluate strings that contain python literals and pull the third element out of the `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a regex. Wrap your string in brackets to make a string representation of a list, then use `ast.literal_eval` to turn it into an actual list.

```
import ast
s = "0, 0, ['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU'], 1"
outer_list = ast.literal_eval('[' + s + ']')
inner_list = outer_list[2]
print(inner_list)
```

You may be tempted to use `eval` instead of `ast.literal_eval`. Resist the temptation. Using `eval` is unsafe because it will evaluate any Python expression, even if it contains nasty stuff such as instructions to delete files from your hard drive. You can use `ast.literal_eval` without fear because it [only parses strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "0, 0, ['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU'], 1"
start = s.find("[")
end = s.rfind("]")
print(s[start:end+1])
['REFERENCED', 'UPTODATE', 'LRU']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for an expression, try something like:

```
"\[([\w\d,']+)\]"
```